# Changing electric plug fixtures outside plate that was painted over and pulled off - nothing fits

Tags: repair

I have a house built in 1960. I'm changing some electric plugs. Not the problem exactly. While I was ill some friends painted some of the rooms and painted over the plate rather than taking it off. I'm having problems finding outlets and plates that fit. The ones I find are two small. And a couple of plates were ripped off the wall. Big problem for me. I am a woman without a lot of extra money but if I know where to buy what I need, I'm good to go. And I have fixtures I need to get off the wall that have been painted over. I need a way to get them off without ripping part of the dry wall.

Comment: We need more info to help you. Where in the world are you? Can we have some pictures of the old outlets, plates, and preferably the wall boxes with a tape measure next to it for scale?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  And can you post photos of the damaged receptacles?

Answer (score 4):

Removing cover plates that have been "stuck" to the drywall by being painted over can be fairly simple. I'd suggest purchasing a simple utility knife from your local hardware store and carefully running that around the edge of the plate where it meets the drywall. This will cut the paint membrane and prevent the painted drywall surface from peeling or tearing when you remove the plate. Once you've done that, just unscrew the plate and remove.

As for replacing the plate, there are oversized replacement wallplates available to conceal larger openings. Just search for "oversized outlet plate" online to see some examples.